# You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

On .NET MVC, I am creating a demo project. When I run my project with IIS Express, it runs fine. But after deploying it to Local IIS, it is showing me an error on my web page:

> You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

How can I get rid of this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem ,`Anonymous Authentication` was disabled in IIS manager.After enabling it started working perfectly.

Feeling good :)

Comment: Glad you found answer to your problem, please mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, with Anonymous Authentication enabled [as mentioned by CodeSniper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280562/88204), under Actions, click Edit. Be sure the **Application pool identify** radio button is selected.

(When I ran into this issue, *Specific User* was selected, with a user account that was no longer valid.)